# jetty startup errors with signer information errors

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Since I've set some maven dependencies to "provided" instead of "compile" scope I got this error when starting up jetty:

- JEE5 application
- should run on WebSphere 7 and Jetty 7
- Spring 3

The error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.setEventListeners(ContextHandler.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.setEventListeners(WebAppContext.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.addEventListener(WebAppContext.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration.preConfigure(TagLibConfiguration.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

The maven section is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>myApp.war</artifactId>
    <!--name??-->

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.5</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
        <cxf.version>2.5.2</cxf.version>
        <jetty.version>7.6.3.v20120416</jetty.version>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- … -->
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>${jetty.version}</version>

                 <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                         <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                         <version>1.4</version>
                     </dependency>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                         <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                         <version>1.1</version>
                         <type>jar</type>
                     </dependency>
                 </dependencies>

                 <configuration>
                     <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                     <webAppConfig>
                         <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                     </webAppConfig>
                     <connectors>
                         <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                             <port>8080</port>
                             <!-- this connector defaults to 1300 for some reason -->
                         </connector>
                     </connectors>
                     <!--
                     <useProvided>true</useProvided>
                     -->
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
```

Can't get the cause. Any hints welcome ;)

Answer (score 5):

It looks as though you are including the servlet API as a provided dependency, and adding this to Jetty's classpath. This is colliding with Jetty's own bundled servlet API classes and causing the exception.

It is absolutely correct to include the servlet API as a provided dependency- the problem is in the `<useProvided>` parameter in the plugin configuration, which is adding the servlet API to the classpath. It would be better to exclude this, and, if you have any other dependencies with provided scope that aren't already in Jetty, then add them to the plugin dependencies, as you have done with `commons-dbcp`.

See also the comments in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-429, which discuss similar potential confusions.

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar problem with **javax.servlet** because there were both 2.4 an 3.0.0 jar-versions in Eclipse Libraries/Maven Dependencies. 
To **fix it in Eclipse** open project's pom.xml, Dependency hierarchy tab, filter by "servlet", choose (right mouse button) unnecessary 2.4(or 2.5) and "Exclude Maven Artifact ..." Thanks to Valery Gorbunov for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the

```
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 <version>1.1</version>
                 <type>jar</type>
             </dependency>
```

in jetty and now it works...seems to another Logger implementation conflicts with commons-logging?! Didn't get the clue yet but for now...it works... Sometimes maven and java are not the best friends or I'm too stupid ;)